# How can I pass a data to a session coming from an array which also comes from database in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I have this problem. I am displaying all the animals which is owned by a certain pet owner. Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['indicator'] = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","appnimal") 
or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysql_error());
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tbl_pet_animal WHERE pet_owner_id='$user'")
or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{echo  "<tr class='even pointer record'>        
        <td class=' '>",$row[1],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[2],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[3],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[4],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[5],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[6],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[7],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[8],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[9],"</td>
        <td class=' '>",$row[10],"</td>
        <td><button type='button' 
                 onClick=location.href='try.php?".$_SESSION['indicator']."=$row[1]'>
       </td>";
 ?>
```

What am I trying to do is let us say, `echo` the `$_SESSION['indicator']` value in another page. This is my code there from another page where I want to `echo` the value:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $indicator="";
    $indicator= $_SESSION['indicator'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","appnimal") 
    or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysql_error());
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT pet_animal_name FROM tbl_pet_animal WHERE pet_animal_name='$indicator'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
       echo ($row['pet_animal_name']);
    }
?>
```

But when I go there, it doesn't display anything. Please help me.

Comment: Where do you assign any value to `$_SESSION['indicator']` ?

Comment: `session_start()` should be always called before any other output. Now you have the  `<strong>` tag before session start..

Comment: Nehal, I assign value to `$_SESSION['indicator']` here:

`<td><button type='button'     onClick=location.href='try.php?".$_SESSION['indicator']."=$row[1]'></td>";
   `

Comment: Ok Hardy. Imma try it now.

Comment: @Hardy, I already called this:

`session_start();
$indicator="";
$indicator= $_SESSION['indicator'];`

before anything else. But I still get nothing.

Comment: also you've got a syntax error when concatenating strings with `,`

Comment: `session_start(); $indicator=""; $indicator= $_SESSION['indicator'];` you are using an empty string which will not work properly when you attempt to set that as part of the querystring. You have not shown the contents of `try.php` ( unless that is the 2nd piece of code ? ) - how does `try.php` process the GET parameters?

Comment: where is `$user` defined and what is its value? Remember that `John` and `john` are two different animals. Check for errors via PHP and MySQL. Your `mysql_error()` does not work with the MySQLi_ API. You need to use `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: You also have a missing `}` brace for your `{echo  "<tr class='even pointer record'>`. Again, use error reporting here http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and inside all your pages, as you do have syntax errors in your code. The same reporting codes will tell you if something is assigned/empty/undefined or not.

Comment: @RamRaider, I just used `$indicator="";` to escape the `unidentified index = indicator`. But I thought, its value will be replaced on whatever the `$_SESSION['indicator']` has.

Comment: But you set `$_SESSION['indicator']=""` ~ empty and you try to use that session variable as a GET parameter so it would become `try.php?=$row[1]` ~ whatever `$row[1]` contains

Comment: @RamRaider, so i must remove it? Okey I'll try.

Comment: @Jeff - using commas in an echo is perfectly fine - it will concatenate comma-separated arguments together for you.

Answer (score 1):

It displays nothing because (at least) in this code, your $_SESSION['indicator'] is "" (empty string) and You probably dont have pat with name "".

You can replace this part in first script :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['indicator'] = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","appnimal")
```

With

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['indicator'] = "ANY_NAME_FROM_DB"; // N.B.: strings can be case-sensitive.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","appnimal")
```

And then check if you get something.

**UPDATE #1 (from comments)**

If you want to assign value on line

`onClick=location.href='try.php?".$_SESSION['indicator']."=$row[1]'`

You should do this instead:

`onClick=location.href='try.php?".$_SESSION['indicator']=$row[1]."'`

Because in your example `"=$row[1]"` is part of string, not php code. It means that `.'=whatever'` will not have any impact on value of your `$_SESSION['indicator']`.

Comment: Imma try it Vladimir. Thanks

Comment: Well, in sql `SELECT pet_animal_name FROM tbl_pet_animal WHERE       pet_animal_name='$indicator' ` you're selecting all rows in table ` tbl_pet_animal` where column `pet_animal_name` is $indicator. So what you should do is 
1. pick any value in column `pet_animal_name` in table `tbl_pet_animal`
2. replace `ANY_NAME_FROM_DB` for this value
3. run your scripts

Comment: I tried to do this:

`$_SESSION['indicator'] = "Dianco";`

since the values from my db is "Dianco", "Matt", "Awit".
It just gives "Dianco" to the other page although I clicked different pet name.

Comment: If I undestand your code correctly, you set your `$_SESSION['indicator']` to `"Dianco"` in first script, and set `$indicator` to `$_SESSION['indicator']` which contains `"Dianco"`. I guess you're trying to set different `SESSION` value on line `onClick=location.href='try.php?".$_SESSION['indicator']."=$row[1]'` is that correct? Or I missed something else?

Comment: Nonetheless, I tried not giving value on my `$_SESSION['indicator']`. But I assigned value on it on `onClick=location.href='try.php?".$_SESSION['indicator']."=$r‌​ow[1]` but still, it won't show anythng.

Comment: Are you trying to set `$_SESSION['indicator']` in this line `onClick=location.href='try.php?".$_SESSION['indicator']."=$r‌​‌​ow[1]`? That is not what is happening ~ you are not assigning a value to the session with that code, you are merely writing a string

Comment: I updated answer, this should resolve your issue, but this needs to be done differently if you want to pass `$_SESSION['indicator'']` as value of `$_GET['indicator']` in url. Now it will do `try.php?Dianco`.